# VBA Chart Coloring

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've got a problem with coloring chosen records from chart with VBA.

I've got some code which colors every record in my chart. Here it is:

```
SeriesCount = MyChart.SeriesCollection.Count
For i = 1 To SeriesCount
    MyChart.SeriesCollection(i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Next
```

What I want is to change color of chosen record, for example 20 on picture below. Thanks for help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can hard code it by position.  Since 20 is the 5th point in the graph you can use this code:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(5).Interior.color = RGB(55, 130, 150)
```

---

If you need to search for 20, it's a little more difficult.

```
Sub color()
    Dim MyChart As Chart
    Set MyChart = ActiveChart

    SeriesCount = MyChart.SeriesCollection.Count
    For i = 1 To SeriesCount
        Set s = MyChart.SeriesCollection(i)
        vals = s.XValues

        For x = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
          If vals(x) = 20 Then
            s.Points(x).Interior.color = RGB(55, 130, 150)
          Else
            s.Points(x).Interior.color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
          End If
        Next x
    Next
End Sub
```

---

**Tested:**

[image]

Comment: What i need is search for value 20, not position :(

Comment: Okay, see edit, I've added a way to iterate through the points in the graph and check to see if it's value is 20.

Comment: I'm getting an error: 
Opject doesn't supprot this property or method. 

(line: vals = s.XValues),

Any ideas, should i change something with my chart?

Comment: What version of Excel are you running?

Comment: Oh, I see.  Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with Access, in fact I didn't know you could create this type of chart in Access. I'll add the Access tag to your post and maybe someone from that realm will chime in.